# How to specify an XmlElement at a different level using XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have a class which I want to serialize to xml. I want to move one of the properties down a level in the generated xml (an element within an element) **without changing the structure of the class**.  Is it possible to do this using XmlSerializer?

An example:

Generated xml:

```
<Person>
    <firstname xmlns=\"http://myschema.com\">John</firstname>
    <postcode xmlns=\"http://myschema.com\">N1 0XE</postcode>
</Person>
```

Desired xml:

```
<Person>
    <firstname xmlns=\"http://myschema.com\">John</firstname>
    <address>
        <postcode xmlns=\"http://myschema.com\">N1 0XE</postcode>
    </address>
</Person>
```

The code:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://myschema.com")]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement("firstname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("postcode")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

Serializer:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);

xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, person);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know to change the generated standard output xml is to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx). So you do not have to change the common structure but you do have to provide the implementation for some methods.

```
public class Person : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlElement("firstname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("postcode")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    #region IXmlSerializable Member

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            FirstName = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        }

        reader.Read(); 

        Postcode = reader.ReadInnerXml();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("firstname ", FirstName);
        writer.WriteStartElement("address");
        writer.WriteElementString("postcode", Postcode);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    #endregion

    // for demo purposes only !
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + ", " + Postcode;
    }

    // source to test the exported file and read it right after!
    Person p = new Person() { FirstName = "jon doe", Postcode = "N1 OX" };

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("export.xml");
    xs.Serialize(sw, p);
    sw.Close();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("export.xml");
    Person p1 = xs.Deserialize(sr) as Person;
    Debug.WriteLine(p1.ToString());
```

@XmlSubElement - there are only a bunch of [**attributes available for xmlSerialization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx). Unfortunatelly there is **no** *subElement* or anything comparable.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to get the sub-element without introducing a new class 'Address', perhaps there's some kind of [XmlSubElement] or similar?

Comment: rewrote answer as of given detail!

Answer (score 1):

There are two other ways out which require no changes whatsoever (not even implementing IXmlSerializable) to your class:

1. a custom XmlWriter which will wrap `<address>` in an element as it is written;
2. post-process XmlSerializer's output with a suitable XSL transform.